# Navigate to another page after setState gives error the 2nd time

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) (not sure if that would be relevant) and trying to handle simple props. However, when I go to ScreenB from ScreenA, it works without any error. After that, if I `pop()` screen to ScreenA and then click again on the same component to go to ScreenB, the app crashes with the following error:

> You attempted to set the key `a` with the value `2` on an
>   object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

Here's a minimal example of the code in `ScreenA: Preview`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { navigationActions } from 'react-native-navigation';

export default class Preview extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }
    };
  }

  _goToFullview() {
    let temp = this.state.data;
    temp.a = 2;
    this.setState({ data: temp });
    this.props.navigator.push({ screen: "App.FullView", passProps: { data: this.state.data } });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{"a: " + this.state.data.a + ","}</Text>
        <Text>{"b: " + this.state.data.b + ","}</Text>
        <Text>{"c: " + this.state.data.c}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this._goToFullview() }>
          <Text>Go To Fullview</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

And here is `ScreenB: FullView`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { navigationActions } from 'react-native-navigation';

class Fullview extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{"a: " + this.props.data.a + ","}</Text>
        <Text>{"b: " + this.props.data.b + ","}</Text>
        <Text>{"c: " + this.props.data.c}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigator.pop({ animated: true, animationType: 'fade' }) }>
          <Text>Go back to preview</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

I believe the above information should be sufficient to understand my problem. Can anyone explain why this would be happening and a simple solution or hint to fix this?

Comment: where are you getting `this.state.poll` from you dont have any poll variable in your state

Comment: mistyped that, it was `this.state.data`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues on react-native-navigation which are related to yours.

Somehow, passing some props to the navigator will make them immutable and frozen.

So in your Screen A when you do

```
this.props.navigator.push({ screen: "App.FullView", passProps: { data: this.state.data } });
```

It is possible that this.state.data become immutable and when you try to modify it the next time it breaks.

Can you try by passing another reference like this :

```
this.props.navigator.push({ screen: "App.FullView", passProps: { data: {...this.state.data} } });
```

To see if it works ?

EDIT :

If yours data.a, data.b and data.c are also object you will maybe need to make a deepClone instead (see : https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/394#issuecomment-255936630)

```
this.props.navigator.push({ screen: "App.FullView", passProps: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data) } });
```